# Tkinter File dialog save is empty

Tags: python, tkinter

I coded a (not finished) Texteditor but wenn I save, the save file is empty

```
import sys
import tkinter
import tkinter.filedialog


root=tkinter.Tk("")
root.title("Text Editor")
text=tkinter.Text(root)
text.grid()

def saveas():
    global text
    t = text.get("1.0", "end-1c")
    savelocation=tkinter.filedialog.asksaveasfilename()
    file1=open(savelocation, "w+")
    file1.write
    file1.close

button=tkinter.Button(root, text="Save", command=saveas)
button.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

i tried nothing besides searching on google(found nothing)

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify what to write to the file and both `write` and `close` are methods, not attributes so they need to be called.

```
import sys
import tkinter
import tkinter.filedialog


root=tkinter.Tk("")
root.title("Text Editor")
text=tkinter.Text(root)
text.grid()

def saveas():
    global text
    t = text.get("1.0", "end-1c")
    savelocation=tkinter.filedialog.asksaveasfilename()
    file1=open(savelocation, "w+")
    file1.write(t)
    file1.close()

button=tkinter.Button(root, text="Save", command=saveas)
button.grid()

root.mainloop()
```